# update a value in a dictionary in nested list in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i have the following data in the mongodb database

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("633c1dc6d3f3452751698332"),
    "col_1" : 153.618639317759,
    "col_2" : 276.7287225,
    "col_3" : "A2",
    "col_4" : "R18",
    "col_5" : [ 
        {
            "f" : 0,
            "Z" : 2.87673627341312
        }, 
        {
            "f" : 1,
            "Z" : 2.87673627341312
        }, 
        {
            "f" : 2,
            "Z" : 2.87673627341312
        }, 
        {
            "f" : 3,
            "Z" : 2.87673627341312
        }, 
        {
            "f" : 4,
            "Z" : 2.87673627341312
        }    
    ]
}
```

i want to update value of the Z in f = 4 in col_5 from 2.87673627341312 to the 1000
so the my data change like the following

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("633c1dc6d3f3452751698332"),
    "col_1" : 153.618639317759,
    "col_2" : 276.7287225,
    "col_3" : "A2",
    "col_4" : "R18",
    "col_5" : [ 
       ....,
        {
            "f" : 4,
            "Z" : 1000
        }    
    ]
}
```

how can i do in Pymongo

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Query

- find the member of `col_5` that has `"f=4"` , `$` holds that member
- and then set `col_5.$.z=1000`

*use updateOne or updateMany based on your needs (multi true is like updateMany)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63695371424f6130d7f12161)

```js
update(
{"col_5": {"$elemMatch": {"f": {"$eq": 4}}}},
{"$set": {"col_5.$.Z": 1000}},
{"multi": true})
```